# Issue when try to send generated PDF file

Tags: php, android, mpdf

i'm having some issue with mpdf.
After generate and download pdf on android system is not possible to send it through message/email service (whatsapp,facebook messanger,Gmail) all stuck.
But the file is opened without problems from the system.

In case of Whatsapp the app return me a this message 'This file is not a document'.
In Gmail case the email stay in the outgoing mail.

With iOS system i don't have this issue the file pdf can be sent through message/email service without problems.

I do not want to advertise any service is just for information

I have already set in my code the header for android like some question on stackoverflow without any result.

Some one can help me?
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Some-Name");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once '/home/[directory]/public_html/[directory]/[directory]/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['setAutoTopMargin' => 'pad','setAutoBottomMargin' => 'pad']);
$mpdf->text_input_as_HTML = true;
$mpdf->SetTitle("MY TITLE");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("My Author");
$header = '<div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">Logo';
$footer = '<div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">My Footer' ;
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('mywatermark image path');
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
$mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.2;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($srting_with_html);
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    $mpdf->Output("My file Title.pdf", "I");
} else {
    $mpdf->Output("My file Title.pdf", "D");
};
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you had a missing quote

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Some-Name");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

require_once '/home/[directory]/public_html/[directory]/[directory]/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['setAutoTopMargin' => 'pad','setAutoBottomMargin' => 'pad']);
$mpdf->text_input_as_HTML = true;
$mpdf->SetTitle("MY TITLE");
$mpdf->SetAuthor("My Author");
$header = '<div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">Logo';
$footer = '<div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">My Footer' ;
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('mywatermark image path');
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
$mpdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 0.2;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($srting_with_html);
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
$mpdf->Output("My file Title.pdf", "I");
}else{
$mpdf->Output("My file Title.pdf", "D");
};
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Oh sorry but my real code does't miss quote. This is my mistake when i edit code for blame paths and other sensitive information.